# Incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8bit UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've been struggling with this issue for a while and the other answers I've seen on SO haven't been able to fix it yet.

The error comes from this line in my view `.html.erb` whenever the user has a name with an accent in it, for example `è` anywhere in the name:

```
console.log(<%= raw current_user.as_json({:include => :roles, :safe => true})%>);
```

From what I can see, when `current_user.as_json` is returned all keys have encoding value of `US-ASCII` and key strings that exist are `UTF-8`. If I check the encoding of the other values by converting them to a string they are also `US-ASCII`.

It seems like when roles is included all the keys are `UTF-8` and if I `to_s` the values they are `US-ASCII`, would this be some sort of configuration error I have?

Changes I have made/Things I've tried:

- I threw `# encoding: UTF-8` at the top of both `rb` files in play.
- My `database.yml` is using mysql2 and has the encoding set to `utf8mb4`
- `application.yml` has `config.encoding = "utf-8"`
- Both the internal and external encodings are set to `Encoding::UTF_8` in `environment.rb`
- The rails console runs into no issues when doing the same actions

I'm assuming there is some sort of issue when converting the hash to a JSON object in the view, but I can't seem to figure out what that issue is.

I'm using Rails `4.2.9` and ruby `2.3.3`

Comment: Note, since you're not using Ruby 1.8 you can always use the more concise hash notation: `include: :roles, safe: true`.

Comment: Are you trying to embed UTF-8 inside of ASCII or the other way around?

Comment: @tadman this is the convention that my work uses. Also, I'm not "trying" to do either, I'm just trying to return a JSON object of the current_user with roles included, I can't seem to see where the error is actually comes from as in my users model the Hash seems to not use ASCII_8BIT at all.